# Explaining Computation of a Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, state-diagram

I am having some trouble interpreting what this Turing machine actually does (i.e., I am uncertain how to explain it in plain English).

[image]

I believe I have created the state diagram correctly using the transition table I was given (although not 100% on this either).

From what I can see this TM will halt in an accepting state `(q2)` whenever the input is of the form

`(a || b || B)*Ba*c(a || b || c || B)*`,

that is any amount of `a`'s, `b`'s, and blanks (but no `c`'s), followed by at least one blank, any amount of `a`'s, and exactly one `c`. Anything can come after since we go left upon finding first `c`.

I suppose my question is

a) Is my work up to this point correct? and

b) Is there a more meaningful explanation of this Turing machine (i.e. a richer description than I wrote of the input that halts in `(q2)`).

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

1. q0 reads left to right, doesn't change the tape, and stops when it hits c.
2. q1 reads left to right, swaps a and b, halts when it sees a B and turns around when it hits an a.
3. The only way to for the TM to halt is if

   - There is a c somewhere on the tape to the right of the initial tape position
   - In q1, the last pass from right to left sees only b and leaves only a between the first c and the rightmost B to the left of c.
4. q1 changes everything between the first c and the rightmost b to the left of that c to a b eventually

Given initial tape configuration >BxBycz, the machine will always halt in configuration >BxB(a^|y|)cz. It accepts any string that contains c.

Your state diagram disagrees with the table in that the table has the transition function defined so that f(q1, a) = (q0, b, L) and f(q1, b) = (q1, a, L), but your diagram shows f(q1, a) = (q1, a, L) and f(q1, b) = (q0, b, L).